# canvas.drawPoint not working in 4.4 or 5.0

Tags: android, canvas

I have been facing this problem since months ago, i couldn't find anything about it.

I have an application with the function canvas.drawPoint and it's never drawing anything in android 4.4 or 5.0 or higher.

But it's perfectly working from 2.3 until 4.2, i actually tested different real devices to say so.

The same for the virtual devices.

The problem is only with points because drawing rectangles or lines with canvas.drawRect or canvas.drawLine is perfectly working even in the same app.

Example:

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400, paint); // working for all devices
for (int ii=0;ii<500+1;ii++) 
        {
            for (int jj=0;jj<500+1;jj++)
            {  canvas.drawPoint(ii, jj, paint);  //not working for higher than 4.4 android version
                } }
```

This will draw the first 400*400 rectangle but not the second 500*500 series of points.

For my real application it is using 2 classes, i actually deleted some calculations, and oncliklistners just to make it simple but not working.

DrawView.java

```
package com.example.hazim.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    int pr=150;int pry=150; int it=23; double cx=-0.1;double cy=0.65;
    Paint paint = new Paint();



    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
        super(context, att); //set the color in the creator of drawview
        paint.setARGB(255, 150,150,150);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, paint); // as a test the drawview display


        double prr=pr; double pryy=pry;


        for (int ii=0;ii<pr+1;ii++) //pass the screen pixels in 2 directions
        {
            for (int jj=0;jj<pry+1;jj++)
            {
                    canvas.drawPoint(ii, jj, paint); 
            }
        }
    }
    //parameter setters
    public void setpr(int a) {pr=a;}
    public void setpry(int a) {pry=a;}
    public void setcx(double a) {cx=a;}
    public void setcy(double a) {cy=a;}

}
```

and here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hazim.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView=null; //instanciation of drawview
    Button bouton=null;
    EditText cx=null;
    EditText cy=null;
    EditText pr=null;
    EditText pry=null;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // display activity main XML

        drawView = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawView1); // load the drawView
        bouton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); // load the button
        cx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02); // load the 4 editTexts
        cy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        pr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
        pry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText04);



    }
}
```

Comment: show us how you declare your `paint` object

Comment: just tried on my L device (5.1) - works fine, so I assume the issue is in your `paint` object

Answer (score 3):

You did not configure your `Paint` properly. You have to set proper stroke width ([Paint#setStrokeWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth(float))), to tell canvas how big your point should be. Otherwise it will be 1px  big which is veeeerrry small on hi res displays, so you don't even see it.

Also since you are using this paint to draw rectangle - I would create separate Paint object just for drawing points:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    ....
    Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
    Paint pointPaint = new Paint();


    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
        super(context, att); //set the color in the creator of drawview
        rectPaint.setAntialias(true);
        rectPaint.setARGB(255, 150,150,150);

        pointPaint.setAntialias(true);
        pointPaint.setColor(Color.RED); //your point color goes here
        pointPaint.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.point_size)); //assuming you specified point size 
                                                                                    //in dp in dimes.xml resource file
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, rectPaint);
        double prr=pr; double pryy=pry;

        for (int ii=0;ii<pr+1;ii++) //pass the screen pixels in 2 directions
        {
            for (int jj=0;jj<pry+1;jj++)
            {
                canvas.drawPoint(ii, jj, pointPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That really worked hero with pointPaint.setAntialias(true);
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The strokeWidth property was missing.